# Fast Report for Rad Studio XE7

Tags: c#

Can someone send me a link to download the **Fast-report VCL 5** for **RAD Studio XE7**  i am not in a position to download from the main site. Please share.

Answer (score 0):

FR5 VCL Embarcdero edition always included in XE7. Run XE7 installer and install FR5